# iOS :viewForHeaderInSection can't get align with cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have this code in my viewForHeaderInSection: of tableViewController

```
 UILabel *l = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 320, 40)] autorelease];
  l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  //l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; //i tried it didn't help!
  l.text= NSLocalizedString(@"My Label:", @"");
```

the label always appears around 35 point off the cell's left side. If i use the UITextAlignmentCenter it works and it goes in center but I want it align with left size of cell. I tried the CGRectZero instead of  CGRectMake(20, 0, 320, 40),  changed x but it didn't work!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first make view with frame (0, 0, 320, 40). Then put label on it.